# Open a file using fgets result doesn't work

Tags: c, file, char, system-calls, fgets

I'm trying to open some files using open().
File names are stored in a temporary file (one filename in each row).
This is the code I'm using:

```
char strbuf[64];

while (fgets (strbuf, sizeof(strbuf), temp)) 
{
    printf("%s\n", strbuf);

    if((txt_fd = open(strbuf, O_RDWR | O_APPEND)) < 0)
    {
      printf("Open error!\n");
      exit(1);
    }       
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Data1.txt
Open error!
```

The weird thing is that if i manually set the open() this way the open() works.

```
txt_fd = open("Data1.txt", O_RDWR | O_APPEND)
```

What's wrong with **strbuf**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try printing value of `txt_fd` in both cases.

Comment: there is a need to remove the last newline.

Comment: in the first case is -1, in the second case is 4.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, so fgets also gets '\n' from the line and I need to remove it? Thanks, I'm gonna try it now!

Comment: Print symbols of strbuf as integer, and you will see some '\n' at the end, for example.

Comment: How can I remove it? I tried to do strncpy(filename, strbuf, strlen(strbuf) -1); and then use filename in the open() but the result is the same...

Comment: `char *p=strchr(strbuf, '\n');if(p) *p = '\0';`

Comment: Thanks, it works! So what we're doing is to find the '\n' occurrence in the string and then, if it exists, we substitute it with the null termination character, right? Anyway thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: _right?_ yes. or `while(fscanf(temp, " %63[^\n]", strbuf)==1)`

Comment: strbuf[strlen(strbuf) - 1] = 0;

Comment: @nightshade , newline is not guaranteed to exist.

Comment: Using `printf("\"%s\"\n", strbuf);` will help show is the beginning or end of `strbuf` has white-space.